# Nested filtering in Excel 2013 pivots

Tags: excel

I have following table configuration in my Excel sheet (let's say that it's some kind of shop inventory):

```
Product | Type    | Producer | Cost per unit
Apple   | fruit   | fruitCo  | 5,00
Apple   | fruit   | bananaCo | 6,00
Banana  | fruit   | bananaCo | 4,00
T-shirt | clothes | clothsCo | 60,00
```

Etc.

And I've created a PivotTable from following data, that groups it by:

```
Filters: Producer, Type
Columns: Product
Rows: <empty>
Values: Sum of Cost
```

I've got two filters, Producer and Type. When I select a Producer from list (f.e bananaCo), the second filter shows me every kind of Type, even those that are not present in the already selected Producer filtering. Is there any way to make this filtering nested, so when I choose a Producer, only the types of product distributed by the selected producer appear in the Type filter list?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem of not but try clicking on the Product field in the pivot and clicking the field settings button from the ribbon (under Options, Active Field) then Layout & Print in the window that appears.
Make sure Show items with no data is deselected.

[image]